# Sending UTF-8 message to send_keys in Selenium Python code for Chrome web browser

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send some text in Gujarati lang as mentioned below.

સમરાદિત્ય ચરિત્ર
      ભવ – ૧
      ભાગ – ૨૫

પ્રથમ ભવ:-
ગુણસેન(રાજા) – અગ્નિશર્મા (પુરોહિત પુત્ર)

રાજમાર્ગ પરથી મહાજનોના ૧૦૮ રથોને રથમહેલ તરફ જતા જોઇને, નગરવાસી લોકો અનેક તર્ક-વિતર્ક કરવા

લાગ્યા. શત્રુઘ્નની હવેલી રાજમાર્ગ પર હતી. તેણે પણ મહાજનોને રાજમહેલ તરફ જતા જોયા

When using the send_keys for Chrome, it is throwing the error.

code

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
input('Enter anyhing once the QR code has been scanned successfully')



#Let proceed with the sending message to all groups
for i in range(grp_list_len):
    name = grp_list_val_data[i]
    message = msg_list_data
    #Select the group
    user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
    user.click()
    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3u328')
    msg_box.send_keys(message)
    send = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3M-N-')
    time.sleep(10)
    send.click()
    print('Message sent successfully to : ',name)
```

Error is as mentioned below.

```
 File "<ipython-input-23-3019c9ccf05a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/Python AI/Python Anaconda projects/WA_msg/WhatsApp message try-2.0.py', wdir='E:/Python AI/Python Anaconda projects/WA_msg')

  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "E:/Python AI/Python Anaconda projects/WA_msg/WhatsApp message try-2.0.py", line 45, in <module>
    msg_box.send_keys(message)

  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})

  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\Rushabh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

Comment: It's an open bug https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3257 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be an open bug with [ChromeDriver](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2269), so unfortunately you're out of luck with that option. You may need to switch to FirefoxDriver instead to get this working.